# How to use React Native to scan pictures and display stored information about the picture

Tags: react-native

I need help to do a mobile app using Native React. I need to use phone camera to take pictures of cards, and have the app to show stored information about the pictures. I'm not sure what library or function I should look into and I can't find related keywords to research more into this.

Answer (score 0):

To use your phone camera, you can use [react-native-camera](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera).

```
npm install react-native-camera --save
```

It can detect in live QRcode or barcode. So you could add one in each image and get the data from another website.

The props called when a barcode or qrcode is found is *onBarCodeRead*.